# How can we find a unique (suboptimal) solution to an optimisation problem with a very large search space?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent, notation, non-convex

A standard linear and unconstrained optimization problem has the following form:

$\max_{x} f(x)$,

For example $f(x) = cos(x)+sin(2x)$, with $-1 \leq x \leq 8$.

The gradient $=0$ will allow finding all the minima and maxima.
But the gradient will not find the unique (and suboptimal) one, the one nearest to $x=4$.

A search method can look for the unique one, but for large search spaces (i.e. neural networks) this is impossible.

Second question: How do you formulate uniqueness mathematically, in an optimization problem, e.g. as a constraint?

[image]

Comment: as it's pretty much impossible to find any optimum for a neural net with a decently large dataset, i think finding a unique suboptimum won't be any less difficult

Comment: I think you need to clarify: 1) What is the first question? 2) In what sense is the maximum near x=4 unique? I count three maximums.

Comment: 1) How can you find a point x*, that has the maximal value for y*=f(x*), but is constrained such that there are no other values x for which f(x)=y*. 
2) It is unique, because x=1 and x=7, the values are f(1)=f(7)=2 (approximately), while f(4)=.5, so it is unique.

Comment: "Unique suboptimum" sounds like a contradiction in terms, because ordinarily a "suboptimum" is any location that yields a value "reasonably" close to an optimum--so there usually are infinitely many such locations.  What exactly do you mean by "suboptimum"?

Comment: A local maximum that is unique.